Measurability in product space induced by completion of product sigma algebra
I am trying to understand the relationship between joint measurability and the measurability of slices in product spaces, as well as how this relates to the measurability of product functions.

Measurability of slices:
Let $f: X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function measurable with respect to the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times Y$. According to Theorem 8.5 of Real and Complex Analysis by Rudin, if $f$ is jointly measurable on $X \times Y$, then the "slices" $f_x(y) = f(x, y)$ (for each fixed $x$) and $f_y(x) = f(x, y)$ (for each fixed $y$) are measurable in their respective $\sigma$-algebras on $Y$ and $X$.

My question is: Does the converse hold?
If the slices $f_x$ (for fixed $x$) are measurable in $Y$, and $f_y$ (for fixed $y$) are measurable in $X$, can we conclude that $f$ is jointly measurable in $X \times Y$?
I understand that the converse does not hold in general for arbitrary $\sigma$-algebras. However, I am specifically interested in the case where $X = Y = \mathbb{R}$, and we are working with the product $\sigma$-algebra generated by the completion of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Does the converse hold in this case?
If not, under what additional conditions can we conclude that $f$ is jointly measurable?

Measurability of product functions:
Now, consider the function $F(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$, where $f$ is measurable in $X$ and $g$ is measurable in $Y$ with respect to their respective $\sigma$-algebras.
Is the function $F(x, y)$ measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times Y$?
If yes what is its generalization to larger class (such as $F(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$,$F(x,y)= \operatorname{max}(f(x),g(y))$etc).


For your first question, the answer is no. A counterexample is given by the indicator function of the Vitali's set $\mathbf{1}_V$.
